# Error in sql syntax when running sql script in jpa

Tags: mysql, jpa

I'm running an MySQL-script within my persistence.xml file in java, to input some values into some MySQL tables:

```
INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Emilie','Knudsen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Aya','Knudsen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Ida','Jørgensen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Ellen','Mortensen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Mathilde','Sørensen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Emilie','Knudsen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Ella','Rasmussen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Maja','Larsen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Sofie','Madsen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Silje','Vad','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Sofie','Larsen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Vigga','Petersen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Victoria','Christensen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Liv','Larsen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Malou','Jørgensen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Merle','Olsen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Alberte','Andersen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Emma','Kristensen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Filippa','Christiansen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Johanne','Poulsen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Vigga','Jørgensen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Ellen','Thomsen','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Caroline','Møller','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Laura','Møller','female'); INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Thea','Knudsen','female');
```

When I ran the script in the MySQL workbench it worked fine (some entries were with the same name, because I used that as a foreign key).

But when i run the same script from my persistence.xml file i get this error:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Aya','Knudsen','female'); INSERT ' at line 1
```

Error Code: 1064

Here is my persistence.xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="samplePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Women?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="*****"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="createData.sql"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When i have tested the syntax, why does this problem occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your "script" to put end-of-line character between all `INSERT` statements. Like this

```
INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Emilie','Knudsen','female'); 
INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Aya','Knudsen','female'); 
INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Ida','Jørgensen','female'); 
INSERT INTO names(name,surname,gender) VALUES('Ellen','Mortensen','female');
```

Some JPA providers can work out where the end of line is and separate the JDBC statements, but others don't do that. Yours seems to be putting all through JDBC in one statement, which will fail, as you have seen. You should also raise a bug on your JPA provider to handle such cases.